# Overriding internal C functions in ffmpeg

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I have a C++ application which uses ffmpeg.

What I want to do is to replace the thread based filter execution with my own task-scheduler based execution.

However, as soon as I try to call a function pointer in my "custom" function I get an access violation, even if the "custom" function is exactly the same as what is in ffmpeg.

What could cause this? Some kind of calling convention thing?

e.g.

```
struct AVFilterInternal {
    int (*execute)(AVFilterContext *ctx, int (*func)(AVFilterContext *ctx, void *arg, int jobnr, int nb_jobs), void *arg,
                   int *ret, int nb_jobs);
};

static int custom_execute(AVFilterContext *ctx, int (*func)(AVFilterContext *ctx, void *arg, int jobnr, int nb_jobs), void *arg,
                           int *ret, int nb_jobs)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < nb_jobs; i++) { // MY goal is to have this as tbb::parallel_for
        int r = func(ctx, arg, i, nb_jobs); // Access Violation. If I replace "func" with an inline implementation everything works fine.
        if (ret)
            ret[i] = r;
    }
    return 0;
}

void init()
{
     /* Create filter graph */

     // For each filter in filtergraph
     reinterpret_cast<AVFilterInternal*>(filter->internal)->execute = custom_execute;
}
```

Comment: What is `func` and where does it come from?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Func it the worker function. ffmpeg calls "execute" internally and provides func.

Comment: Here is an example of how it is called, http://git.libav.org/?p=libav.git;a=blob;f=libavfilter/vf_yadif.c;h=56da9e0e26d8e5f3921bb314776c1bcc83a6b68c;hb=cb79881b49d81dd809dc59c94e002c1de1434cd1#l244